# Python Tkinter rerun the def __init__ from a frame class

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

How do I rerun the **init** from a frame class in tkinter Python?

This is my code - (removed a lot of stuff to simplify it)

```
class HeadlineGame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.container = container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

        moneylabel =tk.Label(self, text="Money: " + str(money))

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        if controller not in self.frames:
            self.frames[controller] = frame = controller(self.container, self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()
q = 0
y = 0

def multifunction(*args):
    for function in args:
        function

def publishwindow():
 global q
 q = 0

def publisharticleimplement():
 pass


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        q = 0
        while q==0:
          print(money)
          q = 1
        publishimg = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/publishbutton.png")
        cb = lambda: multifunction(controller.show_frame(PublishPage), publishwindow())
        publishbutton = tk.Button(self, image=publishimg, borderwidth=0, command= cb)
        publishbutton.image = publishimg
        publishbutton.place(x=503, y=315)

        moneylabel =tk.Label(self, text="Money: " + str(money))
        moneylabel.place(x=0, y=360)

class PublishPage(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            global money
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            fakelogo = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/fakenewslogo.png")
            publishimg = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/publishbutton.png")

            moneylabel =tk.Label(self, text="Money: " + str(money))
            moneylabel.place(x=0, y=360)

            def fakechoice():
              print('xyz')

            cb = lambda: multifunction(controller.show_frame(StartPage), publisharticleimplement())
            publisharticle = tk.Button(self, image=publishimg, borderwidth=0, command=cb)
            publisharticle.image = publishimg
            publisharticle.place(x=503, y=380)

            fakechoice()
```

What I want is to rerun the **init** from the Class Startpage frame so that it updates the whole frame and reruns the entire code and while loop.

Is there anyway to achieve this by putting in a code in the publisharticleimplement function that reruns the def **init** from StartPage?

Any solutions are appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend moving the update process in a separate function called UpdateFrame() and calling it in the init

Comment: How would I call it outside the class then?

Comment: Instance.UpdateFrame()

Comment: Your little while loop is useless. You can replace it with `print(money)`